# Get a GCP project default bucket from cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to get the project's default storage bucket programatically in a google cloud function (project the function is deployed in) ? 
I know if I create an app engine deployment a default bucket gets automatically created and that follows a naming convention that probably I can use to guess the bucket name. But I want to make it more robust and want to fetch it programatically so that I can be a 100 percent sure of the bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code the Default Bucket name because it really is immutable and follows the [same pattern](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket), or you can programmatically send a "listBucket" request and then pull the bucket object from there. Please see the [API details here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-bucket)